# Calculate $a^2+b^2$

Tags: analysis

Factorize $f(x)=x^4+[3]x^3+[6]x^2+[5]x+[3] \in \mathbb{Z}_7[X]$.Let $g(x)$ the irreducible monic polynomial with the greatest degree.If $g([2])=[a] \text{ and } g([3])=[b]$,calculate $a^2+b^2$.

I found that $-3$ is a root of $f(x)$,so $x+3 \mid f(x) \Rightarrow f(x)=(x+3)(x^3+6x+1)$

$$g(x)=x^3+6x+1$$

$$g(2)=8+12+1=21=0 \Rightarrow a=0$$

$$g(3)=3^3+18+1=9 \cdot 3+4+1=2 \cdot 3+5=6+5=11 \Rightarrow b=11$$

$$a^2+b^2=121$$

Have I done something wrong? Because I had this question at a test of multiple choise,and this was not a possible answer.

Comment: If $g(2)=0$ is $g$ irreducible?

Comment: $x^3+6x+1 = (x-2)(x^2+2x+3)$, the last is irreducible

Comment: Oh,yes..you are right!!!! So,is it:

$$g(x)=x^2+2x+3$$

$$a=g(2)=2^2+4+3=11$$

$$b=g(3)=3^2+2 \cdot 3+3=9+6+3=18=4$$

$$a^2+b^2=121+16=137$$

Or have I done something wrong?